# What does "Fisher test error : LDSTP is too small" mean?

Tags: r, workspace

I ran a fisher test and got an error message

`Error in stats::fisher.test(., ...) : 
   FEXACT error 7(location). LDSTP=18630 is too small for this problem,
   (pastp=52.7189, ipn_0:=ipoin[itp=223]=2655, stp[ipn_0]=51.5152).
   Increase workspace or consider using 'simulate.p.value=TRUE`

I saw other posts that you can increase the workspace so I did and it solved the error. But what does this error mean though? Why do I need to increase workspace..? What is LDSTP?

Comment: Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/Lagkouvardos/Rhea/issues/17), which mentions how to increase workspace.